# Gradle maven-publish / Sonatype creates multiple repositories that can't be closed

Tags: maven, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to deploy a library to Maven Central (which I have done many times before) but in this case it contains many different publications for different platforms. The upload by the `maven-publish` plugin works but I end up with multiple repositories in Sonatype with each repository containing a subset of the files:

[image]

As a result, I cannot close the repositories because some files are always missing (only all repositories together contain all files needed to pass Sonatype's validation).

The Sonatype documentation says:

> A separate staging repository is created for every combination of User ID, IP Address, and User Agent.
> (https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/staging-releases/managing-staging-repositories)

All three parameters are identical for the created repositories though so it should create a single one.
This happens when publishing locally and also when publishing from a Github action.

The repo is here: https://github.com/1gravity/Kotlin-Bloc

This is the publish script: https://github.com/1gravity/Kotlin-Bloc/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/bloc-publish.gradle.kts

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Link to the project? Also what I see is that the signing is missing?

Comment: @khmarbaise I added the repo link and the publish script to the question. The signature is missing because it's in a different repository, that's exactly the problem I'm trying to solve. The files are put into different repositories so the signature might end up in a different one than the actual artifact.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with https://github.com/mockk/mockk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `gradle.properties`, you have `org.gradle.parallel=true`.

I had the same issue and resolved it by setting it to `false` for publishing.

You can do so on the command line by publishing with

`./gradlew publish -Dorg.gradle.parallel=false`

Apparently, sonatype does not play well with gradle parallel builds.